# Sybase server build error, missing library files

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

I'm trying to build sybase ase server through sample resource file and i got this error. "error loading shared libraries: libXm.so.4: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory". So ran ldd on srvbuild and found below, two of them are missing.. any idea how to resolve this?
[image]

The OS is RHEL6.5 64bit and its ASE 16, express edition.

environment variables set.
[image]

Comment: can you post the output of echo $ENV.  It could be the ASE environment variables are not getting set properly.  $SYBASE, $SYBASE_ASE, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and others need to exist for everything to work.

Comment: i've edited the description with details.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to install missing libraries on you system.

libXm is part of openmotif package:

[libXm.so.4 (32bit)](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXm.so.4)

[libXm.so.4 (64bit)](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXm.so.4()(64bit))

libXp is part of X.Org X11 runtime library:

[libXp.so.6 (32bit)](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXp.so.6)

[libXp.so.6 (64bit)](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXp.so.6()(64bit))

EDIT: I created a support case on SAP site and they responded me with a list of necessary packages. First, there is a site [System requirements for Linux](https://help.sap.com/viewer/23c3bb4a29be443ea887fa10871a30f8/16.0.3.5/en-US/6302c568328c4f599bd0209e6beb1e4c.html) (this one is for ASE 16.0 SP03 PL05, but you can change it in the upper right corner) where you can find that you need to setup $LANG environment variable first. Then there is referral to SAP KBA Note [2489781](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2489781), which is accessible only with valid credentials, so I picked important information below (again valid for ASE 16.0 SP03 PL05):

System: Red Hat

Hardware: x86_64 processor (Intel Xeon with EM64T)

Libraries:

- kernel-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
- glibc-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64
- compat-glibc-2.5-46.2.x86_64
- glibc.i686 (Redhat 7 requires 32-bit libraries to execute the isql and dscp utilities)

Additional Linux Libraries:

- openmotif-2.3.1-2.el5
- libXp-1.0.0-8.1.el5
- libXt-1.0.2-3.1.fc6
- libXtst-1.0.1-3.1
- libXi-1.6.1-1
- libXmu-1.0.2-5
- libXext-1.0.1-2.1
- libSM-1.0.1-3.1
- libICE-1.0.1-2.1
- libX11-1.0.3-9.el5

With all of above installed, you should be able to build and run this version of ASE.